# Get output of SQL query when using PHP

Tags: php, sql

Following a tutorial, I execute SQL queries using PHP like so:

```
$query = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT id FROM Families WHERE family_name = ?");
$query -> bindValue(1, $family_name);

$query -> execute();

$query2 = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE family_id = ?");
$query2 -> bindValue(1, $query); //ISSUE IN THIS LINE

$query2 -> execute();
```

My question: How do I take the result of the first query, the `id`, and put it as input in the second query?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not read the result from the first query, and use that as an input for the second query? Or why not use a `JOIN` to avoid having **two** queries?

Comment: Tbh, I didn't even consider `JOIN` as an option, forgot that was a think. What I had tried included doing `$result = $query -> execute(); `, which did nothing, trying to see what `$query` has inside it and others. But the solution was found, fortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch the result, `execute` only runs the query in db, it does not get the values, try this which will return an array:

```php
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

If you know you only want one result, try:

```php
$result = $query->fetch();
```

Comment: So, essentially, `execute()` just executes the query in the Database, as if I had ran the query myself in the console of the db, but in order to "command" the db to send the results, I have to use a `fetch()` function?

Comment: @KostasM Yes. Also FYI you can run a more performant query using join, but again for getting the result data you need to `fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

store the first query result in an object like

```
 $result = $query->execute();
    
    if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
      $family = $Result->fetch_object();
      
      $query2 = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE family_id = ?");
      $query2 -> bindValue(1, $family->id);

      $query2 -> execute();
    }
```

Please use `limit 1` so that object don't return more than one id

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM Families WHERE family_name = ?");
$stmt1->bindValue(1, $family_name);
$stmt1->execute();
$family = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //You can use fetch inorder to return 1 result for more use fetchAll();

//Here $family is now an object array 
//Stored id in $family_id variable
$family_id = $family->family_id; //All the columns will save as properties now so you can easily access each of them

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE family_id = ?");
$stmt2->bindValue(1, $family_id);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //Used fetchAll method because It's returning more than 1 result I guess
```

Comment: Is `fetch()` and `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` different in any way? Like, does the first one return an array while the second returns an Object, with its attributes being the Database's columns?

Comment: Here PDO::FETCH_OBJ is just the style of returning results there are some other ways too.To be more object oriented use PDO::FETCH_OBJ inside fetch() or fetchAll() from that array the keys (columns in the table) are saving as properties.
Example: username is the column name have $user = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); , you can access the username by $user->username;

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the Queries:

```
SELECT f.* FROM Families INNER JOIN Categories c on c.id = f.family_id WHERE c.family_name  = ?
```

Fetch the result as [Mohsen Nazari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16430884/mohsen-nazari) has stated